# How to disable Tls 1.3 in nodejs request

Tags: node.js, ssl, encryption, request, electron

I want to disable tls 1.3 and use specific cipher suites when sending request using npm request package inside my electron app.

I found when I run it by "npm start" which actaully is "electron ."(my function is in main process), it sents tls client handshake message with an extra field "extension_supported_versions" saying supporting tls1.3. And carrying 46 cypher suites.

If it is ran by "node test.js", then only 18 cipher suites is sent out.

Reuqest package version is 2.88.0 in both cases. I wonder why such difference exists. Seems electron did something to impact the cipher suite selection process of request package.

```
"ELectron ."
Frame 80754: 305 bytes on wire (2440 bits), 305 bytes captured (2440 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: IntelCor_18:36:61 (78:0c:b8:18:36:61), Dst: Tp-LinkT_9d:52:bc (bc:46:99:9d:52:bc)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.101, Dst: 27.148.140.18
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 53505, Dst Port: 443, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 251
Transport Layer Security
    TLSv1.3 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Length: 246
        Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
            Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
            Length: 242
            Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
            Random: b5e74f961551b2deda4486f6d138b97c0d12419b756cda10…
            Session ID Length: 32
            Session ID: 4e7b9be07d3d89c6e9d9ffb7bbb6fbf971b5d2912f9e8584…
            Cipher Suites Length: 36
            Cipher Suites (18 suites)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x1301)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x1302)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0x1303)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca9)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca8)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x000a)
            Compression Methods Length: 1
            Compression Methods (1 method)
            Extensions Length: 133
            Extension: server_name (len=17)
                Type: server_name (0)
                Length: 17
                Server Name Indication extension
                    Server Name list length: 15
                    Server Name Type: host_name (0)
                    Server Name length: 12
                    Server Name: api.nike.com
            Extension: extended_master_secret (len=0)
                Type: extended_master_secret (23)
                Length: 0
            Extension: renegotiation_info (len=1)
                Type: renegotiation_info (65281)
                Length: 1
                Renegotiation Info extension
            Extension: supported_groups (len=8)
                Type: supported_groups (10)
                Length: 8
                Supported Groups List Length: 6
                Supported Groups (3 groups)
            Extension: ec_point_formats (len=2)
                Type: ec_point_formats (11)
                Length: 2
                EC point formats Length: 1
                Elliptic curves point formats (1)
            Extension: session_ticket (len=0)
                Type: session_ticket (35)
                Length: 0
                Data (0 bytes)
            Extension: signature_algorithms (len=20)
                Type: signature_algorithms (13)
                Length: 20
                Signature Hash Algorithms Length: 18
                Signature Hash Algorithms (9 algorithms)
            Extension: key_share (len=38)
                Type: key_share (51)
                Length: 38
                Key Share extension
            Extension: psk_key_exchange_modes (len=2)
                Type: psk_key_exchange_modes (45)
                Length: 2
                PSK Key Exchange Modes Length: 1
                PSK Key Exchange Mode: PSK with (EC)DHE key establishment (psk_dhe_ke) (1)
            Extension: supported_versions (len=5)
                Type: supported_versions (43)
                Length: 5
                Supported Versions length: 4
                Supported Version: TLS 1.3 (0x0304)
                Supported Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)

"Node test.js"
Frame 80283: 287 bytes on wire (2296 bits), 287 bytes captured (2296 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: IntelCor_18:36:61 (78:0c:b8:18:36:61), Dst: Tp-LinkT_9d:52:bc (bc:46:99:9d:52:bc)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.101, Dst: 27.155.111.241
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 53496, Dst Port: 443, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 233
Transport Layer Security
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Length: 228
        Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
            Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
            Length: 224
            Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
            Random: 0193f22cc60e33bca73d481c887826386fda6bd2cfb12e48…
            Session ID Length: 0
            Cipher Suites Length: 92
            Cipher Suites (46 suites)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009e)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0067)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x006b)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00a3)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca9)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca8)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xccaa)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8 (0xc0af)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM (0xc0ad)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8 (0xc0a3)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM (0xc09f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x00a2)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8 (0xc0ae)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM (0xc0ac)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8 (0xc0a2)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM (0xc09e)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc024)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x006a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0040)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0039)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0038)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0033)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0032)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8 (0xc0a1)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM (0xc09d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8 (0xc0a0)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM (0xc09c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x003d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff)
            Compression Methods Length: 1
            Compression Methods (1 method)
            Extensions Length: 91
            Extension: server_name (len=17)
                Type: server_name (0)
                Length: 17
                Server Name Indication extension
                    Server Name list length: 15
                    Server Name Type: host_name (0)
                    Server Name length: 12
                    Server Name: api.nike.com
            Extension: ec_point_formats (len=4)
                Type: ec_point_formats (11)
                Length: 4
                EC point formats Length: 3
                Elliptic curves point formats (3)
            Extension: supported_groups (len=10)
                Type: supported_groups (10)
                Length: 10
                Supported Groups List Length: 8
                Supported Groups (4 groups)
            Extension: session_ticket (len=0)
                Type: session_ticket (35)
                Length: 0
                Data (0 bytes)
            Extension: encrypt_then_mac (len=0)
                Type: encrypt_then_mac (22)
                Length: 0
            Extension: extended_master_secret (len=0)
                Type: extended_master_secret (23)
                Length: 0
            Extension: signature_algorithms (len=32)
                Type: signature_algorithms (13)
                Length: 32
                Signature Hash Algorithms Length: 30
                Signature Hash Algorithms (15 algorithms)
```

Comment: **1)** Electron uses BoringSSL and node uses OpenSSL - that is why you see different cipher suits.  **2)** Why would you want to disable modern protocols which are considered as more secure (your application will pick / fallback to cipher during handshake so it does not make sense to shrink capabilities of your app )

Comment: Thanks. Regarding 2), my app needs to talk to a server which doesn't work well with Tls 1.3 though it claims so

Comment: Is it possible to use OpenSSL rathen than BoringSSL in electron? I want to interact with server which I have no control via OpenSSL. @MaximSagaydachny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can downgrade to tls1.2 by specifying method "TLSv1_2_method":

```
var https = require('https');

var options = {
  hostname: 'example.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET',
  secureProtocol:'TLSv1_2_method'
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});
```

And if the server is part of your project I would advice to fix server side instead of crippling your client app.

Comment: I am using npm  request module in client side. Its usage is very similar with https .request. But I am not sure whether substitution may cause any problem. Anyway, I figured out below works too. const request = require('request').defaults({
  timeout: 10000,
  maxVersion: 'TLSv1.2',
  ciphers: ciphers.join(':')
});